# Android json/gson deserialization

Tags: android, arrays, json, gson

I am trying to parse the following json array that I receive from my php file:

actionsArray = [["19.431","19.438"],[["8","107"],[]],["u1","u2"]]

I'm primarily interested in accessing the array [["8","107"],[]]; however, I get the error, "com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Expecting array but found object: Name: null Grams: null 0 Actions: null

Here's an excerpt from my code:

User class contains:   String name; int[] actions; String grams

```
            JSONArray inputarray;
            try {
                int[] userActionsArray = new int[0];
                inputarray = new JSONArray(br.readLine());

                JSONArray gramsArray = (JSONArray)inputarray.get(0);
                JSONArray actionsArray = (JSONArray)inputarray.get(1);
                JSONArray namesArray = (JSONArray) inputarray.get(2);

                User[] values = new User[namesArray.length()];

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                *User userAction = gson.fromJson(inputarray.toString(), User.class); 
                //error occurs on the above line*
                ...
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs usually when you try to parse array but service is responding as object. So first test the response you are getting then try to parse accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A `JSONArray` is from org.json, which the .toString() method returns as `["first","second"]` (source available [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONArray.java))

You need your JSON to look like: `{ myArray : [ "first", "second" ] }` for Gson to parse it... Where your POJO (in your case `User.class`) should look like this:

```
public User {
 String[] myArray;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. This makes sense but I'm not sure what the proper way is to get my JSONArray to follow the format you specified { myArray : ["first", "second"] }. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you create a loop and just print all the lines so we can see the entire JSON? (Just loop over br.readLine() and print it out). Or are you manually generating the JSON?

Comment: I was able to get through the issue after using ArrayList objects. I gave up on the gson and kept the JSONArrays. I retrieved the JSONArray from a php file. Thanks for your help (+1).